# Is there any 64 bit version of skype available ?

Tags: apt

I was just trying to install skype on my fresh Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit but I have discovered that I would require a lot of my already installed libraries to be installed in 32 bit version just as :

```
$ sudo apt-get install skype
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gcc-4.8-base:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libasyncns0:i386 libaudio2:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386
  libavahi-common3:i386 libc6:i386 libcomerr2:i386 libcups2:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libdbusmenu-qt2:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386
  libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386 libflac8:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgcc1:i386 libgcrypt11:i386
  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgnutls26:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386
  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 libice6:i386 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386
  libjson-c2:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms1:i386 libllvm3.3:i386 liblzma5:i386 libmng1:i386
  libmysqlclient18:i386 libogg0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libpcre3:i386 libpng12-0:i386 libpulse0:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386
  libqt4-declarative:i386 libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386 libqt4-script:i386 libqt4-sql:i386 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 libqt4-xml:i386
  libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqtgui4:i386 libqtwebkit4:i386 libsamplerate0:i386 libselinux1:i386 libsm6:i386 libsndfile1:i386 libspeexdsp1:i386
  libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libtasn1-3:i386 libtiff5:i386 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 libuuid1:i386 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386
  libwrap0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386
  libxfixes3:i386 libxi6:i386 libxml2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxss1:i386 libxt6:i386 libxv1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 mysql-common skype-bin:i386
  sni-qt:i386 zlib1g:i386
Suggested packages:
  nas:i386 glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386 rng-tools:i386 libglide3:i386 gnutls-bin:i386 krb5-doc:i386 krb5-user:i386 libvisual-0.4-plugins:i386
  gstreamer-codec-install:i386 gnome-codec-install:i386 gstreamer0.10-tools:i386 gstreamer0.10-plugins-base:i386 jackd2:i386 liblcms-utils:i386 pulseaudio:i386
  libqt4-declarative-folderlistmodel:i386 libqt4-declarative-gestures:i386 libqt4-declarative-particles:i386 libqt4-declarative-shaders:i386 qt4-qmlviewer:i386
  libqt4-dev:i386 libthai0:i386 libicu48:i386 qt4-qtconfig:i386
Recommended packages:
  xml-core:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc-4.8-base:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libasyncns0:i386 libaudio2:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386
  libavahi-common3:i386 libc6:i386 libcomerr2:i386 libcups2:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libdbusmenu-qt2:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386
  libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386 libflac8:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgcc1:i386 libgcrypt11:i386
  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgnutls26:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386
  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 libice6:i386 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386
  libjson-c2:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms1:i386 libllvm3.3:i386 liblzma5:i386 libmng1:i386
  libmysqlclient18:i386 libogg0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libpcre3:i386 libpng12-0:i386 libpulse0:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386
  libqt4-declarative:i386 libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386 libqt4-script:i386 libqt4-sql:i386 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 libqt4-xml:i386
  libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqtgui4:i386 libqtwebkit4:i386 libsamplerate0:i386 libselinux1:i386 libsm6:i386 libsndfile1:i386 libspeexdsp1:i386
  libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libtasn1-3:i386 libtiff5:i386 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 libuuid1:i386 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386
  libwrap0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386
  libxfixes3:i386 libxi6:i386 libxml2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxss1:i386 libxt6:i386 libxv1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 mysql-common skype
  skype-bin:i386 sni-qt:i386 zlib1g:i386
0 upgraded, 106 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 68,5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 223 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Is there any 64 bit version for 13.10 available to avoid installed all of those libs ?

Comment: No, for linux there isn't.

Comment: Well why do you care? It's not like Skype is using a lot of RAM....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Skype is a native 32 bit application.  There is no 64-bit version of Skype. Skype is a 32-bit program but works well on 64-bit systems.

To install Skype on 64bit Ubuntu, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
sudo apt-get update
wget -O skype-install.deb http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-deb
sudo dpkg -i skype-install.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```